# CKAN resource_create API

Tags: node.js, ckan, superagent

Am trying to read from list of files placed in a location using NodeJS and create resources for those files in CKAN. 
Am using CKAN API v3 (/api/3) to create the resource.

NodeJS library used for iterating through files in a location : **filehound**

CKAN API Used : **/api/3/action/resource_create**

Code to iterate over files (please don't run it; it's only a sample snippet) :

```js
// file operations helper
const fileHound = require("filehound");

// filesystem
const fs = require("fs");

// to make http requests
const superagent = require("superagent");

var basePath = "/test-path", packageId = "8bf37d22-0c25-40c0-8faa-7de12ff927f5";

var files = fileHound.create()
    .paths(basePath)
    .find();

files.then(function (fileNames) {
  if (Array.isArray(fileNames)){
    for (var fileName of fileNames) {
        superagent
                    .post("http://test-ckan-domain.com/api/3/action/resource_create")
                    .set("Authorization", "78d5d219-37de-41f7-9443-188bc564051e")
                    .field("package_id", packageId)
                    .field("name", fileName)
                    .field("format", "CSV")
                    .attach("upload", fs.createReadStream(fileName))
                    .end(function (err, res) {
                        if (!err) console.log(fileName ,"Status Code ", res.statusCode);
                        else console.log("Error ", err);
                    });
    }
  }
});
```

After iterating through the files and uploading them to CKAN by creating a new resource, CKAN responds back with "success: true" and "id" of the resource created with HTTP status code 200.

However, only a few resource(s) are created and few are not. Am using CKAN's frontend to verify if the resource was created under a package/dataset (As the response from the Resource Creation API is successful).

Is it a known issue with CKAN? or am i going wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

You've probably solved this by now, but given that some packages are just missing but you only get 200 success messages, I'm wondering if your for loop just isn't working correctly. Be careful with the syntax; I think declaring var filename inside the loop like that might be wrong.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of